# Script performs very slowly even when it runs asynchronously

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I've written a script in ***`asyncio`*** in association with ***`aiohttp`*** library to parse the content of a website asynchronously. I've tried to apply the logic within the following script the way it is usually applied in ***`scrapy`***.

However, when I execute my script, it acts like how syncronous libraries like ***`requests`*** or ***`urllib.request`*** do. Therefore, it is very slow and doesn't serve the purpose.

I know I can get around this by defining all the next page link within the ***`link`*** variable. But, am I not doing the task with my existing script in the right way already?

Within the script what `processing_docs()` function does is collect all the links of the different posts and pass the refined links to the `fetch_again()` function to fetch the title from it's target page. There is a logic applied within `processing_docs()` function which collects the next_page link and supply the same to `fetch()` function to repeat the same. `This next_page call is making the script slower whereas we usually do the same in`scrapy`and get expected performance.`

***My question is: How can I achieve the same keeping the existing logic intact?***

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
from lxml.html import fromstring
from urllib.parse import urljoin

link = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"

async def fetch(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            text = await response.text()
            result = await processing_docs(session, text)
        return result

async def processing_docs(session, html):
        tree = fromstring(html)
        titles = [urljoin(link,title.attrib['href']) for title in tree.cssselect(".summary .question-hyperlink")]
        for title in titles:
            await fetch_again(session,title)

        next_page = tree.cssselect("div.pager a[rel='next']")
        if next_page:
            page_link = urljoin(link,next_page[0].attrib['href'])
            await fetch(page_link)

async def fetch_again(session,url):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        text = await response.text()
        tree = fromstring(text)
        title = tree.cssselect("h1[itemprop='name'] a")[0].text
        print(title)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*(fetch(url) for url in [link])))
    loop.close()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whole point of using asyncio is that you may run multiple fetches concurrently (in parallel to each other). Let's look at your code:

```
for title in titles:
    await fetch_again(session,title)
```

This part means that each new `fetch_again` will be started only after previous was awaited (finished). If you do things this way, yes, there's no difference with using sync approach.

To invoke all power of asyncio start multiple fetches concurrently using `asyncio.gather`:

```
await asyncio.gather(*[
    fetch_again(session,title)
    for title 
    in titles
])
```

You'll see significant speedup.

---

You can go event futher and start `fetch` for next page concurrently with `fetch_again` for titles:

```
async def processing_docs(session, html):
        coros = []

        tree = fromstring(html)

        # titles:
        titles = [
            urljoin(link,title.attrib['href']) 
            for title 
            in tree.cssselect(".summary .question-hyperlink")
        ]

        for title in titles:
            coros.append(
                fetch_again(session,title)
            )

        # next_page:
        next_page = tree.cssselect("div.pager a[rel='next']")
        if next_page:
            page_link = urljoin(link,next_page[0].attrib['href'])

            coros.append(
                fetch(page_link)
            )

        # await:
        await asyncio.gather(*coros)
```

---

**Important note**

While such approach allows you to do things much faster you may want to limit number of concurrent requests at the time to avoid significant resources usage on both your machine and on server.

You can use `asyncio.Semaphore` for this purpose:

```
semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(10)

async def fetch(url):
    async with semaphore:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(url) as response:
                text = await response.text()
                result = await processing_docs(session, text)
            return result
```

Comment: Perfect!!! Thansk a lot for your invaluable suggestion and solution @Mikhail Gerasimov.

Comment: @asmitu you're welcome! Just don't forget to use Semaphore or site may eventually ban your crawler :)

Comment: When I try the script defining semaphore, It gets stuck somewhere within the process and stay right there. I tried with Boundedsemaphore as well but gets the same behavior. Can you tell what might be the issues @Mikhail Gerasimov? Thanks again.

Comment: @asmitu can you change code like this `session.get(url, timeout=5)` (in both places) and check if you get timeout error? It probably has nothing to do with semaphore, but with SO restrictions about crawlers. I guess at some point site just starts to deliver pages with bigger delay. If you want to grab SO data consider using theirs [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) to avoid such situations.

Comment: @asmitu seems ok to me :) Only one more thing that should probably be added - timeouts. Default timeout in aiohttp is [5 minutes](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#timeouts) you'll probably want to get exception sooner on fail.