# My script encounters an error when it is supposed to run asynchronously

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I've written a script in python using `asyncio` association with `aiohttp` library to parse the names out of pop up boxes initiated upon clicking on contact info buttons out of diffetent agency information located within a table from [this website](https://www.tursab.org.tr/en/travel-agencies/search-travel-agency?sayfa=1) asynchronously. The webpage displayes the tabular contents across 513 pages.

I encountered this error `too many file descriptors in select()` when I tried with `asyncio.get_event_loop()` but when I came across [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675410/python-asyncio-aiohttp-valueerror-too-many-file-descriptors-in-select-on-win) I could see that there is a suggestion to use `asyncio.ProactorEventLoop()` to avoid such error so I used the latter but noticed that, even when I complied with the suggestion,  the script collects the names only from few pages until it throws the following error. How can i fix this?

```
raise client_error(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host www.tursab.org.tr:443 ssl:None [The semaphore timeout period has expired]
```

This is my try so far with:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

links = ["https://www.tursab.org.tr/en/travel-agencies/search-travel-agency?sayfa={}".format(page) for page in range(1,514)]
lead_link = "https://www.tursab.org.tr/en/displayAcenta?AID={}"

async def get_links(url):
    async with asyncio.Semaphore(10):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(url) as response:
                text = await response.text()
                result = await process_docs(text)
            return result

async def process_docs(html):
    coros = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
    items = [itemnum.get("data-id") for itemnum in soup.select("#acentaTbl tr[data-id]")]
    for item in items:
        coros.append(fetch_again(lead_link.format(item)))
    await asyncio.gather(*coros)

async def fetch_again(link):
    async with asyncio.Semaphore(10):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(link) as response:
                text = await response.text()
                sauce = BeautifulSoup(text,"lxml")
                try:
                    name = sauce.select_one("p > b").text
                except Exception: name = ""
                print(name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.ProactorEventLoop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*(get_links(link) for link in links)))
```

In short, What the `process_docs()` function does is collect `data-id` numbers from each pages to reuse them as the prefix of this `https://www.tursab.org.tr/en/displayAcenta?AID={}` link to collect the names from pop up boxes. One such id is `8757` and one such qualified links therefore `https://www.tursab.org.tr/en/displayAcenta?AID=8757`.

Btw, If I change the highest number used in the `links` variable to 20 or 30 or so, It goes smoothly.

Comment: Are you sure that that is the correct way to use `asyncio.Semaphore`? Your code creates a `Semaphore` with value 10 and only acquires it once, so it basically does nothing. You probably want to create the `Semaphore` *outside* those functions and pass it around to all the `get_links` calls instead...

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Bakuriu. I found that idea (using semaphore in such way) from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53718961/script-performs-very-slowly-even-when-it-runs-asynchronously).

Comment: Check the code you linked in your last comment carefully! You are **not** doing the same thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
async def get_links(url):
    async with asyncio.Semaphore(10):
```

You can't do such a thing: it means that on each function call new semaphore instance will be created, while you need to single semaphore instance for all requests. Change your code this way:

```
sem = asyncio.Semaphore(10)  # module level

async def get_links(url):
    async with sem:
        # ...


async def fetch_again(link):
    async with sem:
        # ...
```

You can also return default loop once you're using semaphore correctly:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(...)
```

Finally, you should alter both `get_links(url)` and `fetch_again(link)` to do parsing outside of semaphore to release it as soon as possible, before semaphore is needed inside `process_docs(text)`.

Final code:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

links = ["https://www.tursab.org.tr/en/travel-agencies/search-travel-agency?sayfa={}".format(page) for page in range(1,514)]
lead_link = "https://www.tursab.org.tr/en/displayAcenta?AID={}"

sem = asyncio.Semaphore(10)

async def get_links(url):
    async with sem:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(url) as response:
                text = await response.text()
    result = await process_docs(text)
    return result

async def process_docs(html):
    coros = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
    items = [itemnum.get("data-id") for itemnum in soup.select("#acentaTbl tr[data-id]")]
    for item in items:
        coros.append(fetch_again(lead_link.format(item)))
    await asyncio.gather(*coros)

async def fetch_again(link):
    async with sem:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(link) as response:
                text = await response.text()
    sauce = BeautifulSoup(text,"lxml")
    try:
        name = sauce.select_one("p > b").text
    except Exception:
        name = "o"
    print(name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*(get_links(link) for link in links)))
```

Comment: Sorry to have not been able to comply with your guideline about using semaphore in my script @Mikhail Gerasimov. I ran your script and encountered this viscious error `too many file descriptors in select()`. Moreover, it runs ver very slowly. Plus one for the correct usage of semaphore.

Comment: @asmitu "it runs ver very slowly" - do you mean the exact code from this answer? It's not slow, it just doesn't always find selectors. To see it add prints after both `await response.text()`. If you still think it's slow, you can increase value you init semaphore with, for example - `asyncio.Semaphore(20)`. I can't reproduce `too many file descriptors in select()`, can you specify time script works before this error occurs in your case?

Comment: Thanks for your solution @Mikhail Gerasimov. Should I stick to the way you indented your script? I was asking this because the way I indented in my above script was intentional cause I tried to follow how [the last example given in this blog](http://edmundmartin.com/concurrent-crawling-in-python/). Will be very happy to hear anything from you on this. Btw, this error `too many file descriptors in select()` still persists. FYI, I'm on windows 32.

Comment: @asmitu I didn't pay much attention to indentation, you can do it as you see fit. Usually good idea is to follow [PEP 8](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/style/). "this error ... still persists" - unfortunately I can't reproduce it, nor can I see why it should appear. Only possible thought I have so far is that some previous run of older scripts versions acquired most of the descriptors. Did you try to restart the computer before running final script version?